# Writing a task in VxWorks

Tags: c, vxworks

I am trying to understand how can I write tasks for VxWorks. I have VxWorks on a board that is mounted on a development board.

I can access the board through Putty and a serial terminal connected to the UART of the system. How can I write other tasks (maybe to communicate with other UARTs or other Serial Interfaces) ?

And how do I know where to find the documentation describing how I can access those serial interfaces? (for example write/read methods, which file to include etc)*

Thank you

Comment: you are probably better off asking windriver support

Comment: You might checkk https://labs.windriver.com/vxworks-sdk/#read where you can easily play with the envionment and build small programs running either in kernel space or in user space.

Comment: If you enter the command "devs" on the Shell (through the UART) you would see the list of serial interfaces recognized by VxWorks. Then you can easily use open(), write() on device with name like "tyCo" or "ttyS".

Answer (score 0):

VxWorks is cross development environment, so you need a licensed development system on Windows or Linux desktop to create applications.

Then you load the compiled code on the target reference board as process/RTP or LKM/DKM. How you get it there varies by board: FTP, TFTP, removable USB or SD card....

At the C shell on booted system you can start a task in the kernel context with any public symbol. But if your working with deployed system, it shouldn't have the C shell, that's a serious security risk :)

Try..

```
->  sp printf, "\nHello VxWorks World!\n"
```